# stylus not allowing styles to take affect

Tags: css, pug, stylus

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it? Here is the file:

```
global-reset()

*
    box-sizing border-box
    font-size 16px
    font-family sans-serif

.header
        background #e1e1e1
        height 20em
    border-bottom 5px solid #000
    position relative

.header:before
    position absolute
        display block
        content ''
    border-bottom 5px solid red
    height 100%
        width 100%
        box-sizing border-box

.nav
    display flex
    align-items center
    justify-content flex-end
    padding-top 1em

    ul, li
        list-style none
        display inline
        margin-left 1em
        margin-right 1em

        a
            text-decoration none
            color #999

.title
    display flex
    align-items center
    justify-content center
    padding-top 2em

    h1
        padding-top 1em
        font-size 2em
        font-weight 600

.sub-title
    min-height 8em
    display flex
    align-items center
    justify-content center

    h2
        color #333
```

It is a very basic stylus file but for some odd reason the styles for the bottom-border that's in the .header and .header:before section isn't taking effect. The background colour and the display alignments/padding are styled just fine though.

[image: here it is]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think from what you're writing in the "comment" answer and from what you've post that you should look into the whitespaces. Replace all tabs with spaces. Stylus is whitespace based, thus using both tabs and spaces will make your life miserable.

Answer (score 0):

I am using atom as a text editor. I seems as the code wasn't consistently tabbed in, some spaces some tabs. I came to this conclusion while looking over the code in my question about. The code didn't look like that in the text editor.